# Is there a way to see Rails test coverage as 'methods covered / methods not covered,' rather than line by line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Using a gem like [SimpleCov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) I can see my test coverage on a line-by-line basis for all the files I specify. Is there a way to see test coverage on a method-by-method basis? For example, if my tests engaged a method at all, that method would be considered 'covered.'

Answer (score 0):

> if my tests engaged a method at all, that method would be considered
>   'covered.'

That's a very arbitrary definition of covered methods. What if it has 100 lines but it returns on first guard clause?

Because of this (I imagine) this is not feasible to implement - there would be a problem to even agree what is a covered method.

Such metric would lie (reporting bigger coverage). If you assumed that method is covered if all lines are covered - it would lie too, reporting smaller coverage.

Note: line coverage is also lying a bit (check ternary operators for example), but it's the smallest liar...

Comment: I'm specifically looking for more arbitrary coverage indicators. Not really interested in being convinced otherwise.